# Copying a working chart from a spreadsheet to a document results with "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-docs

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains charts which are properly displayed. When I am using a GAS to copy these charts to a Google document some of the charts are properly displayed in the document while others (which are displayed properly in the spreadsheet) are displaying the message "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type".

Since these are working charts I am not sure why I get this message. Is there a workaround to this problem or a known issue?

Any advise will help.

Thx!

Comment: You can refer to these questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216377/google-chart-api-error-all-series-on-a-given-axis-must-be-of-the-same-data-type   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476299/all-series-on-a-given-axis-must-be-of-the-same-data-type

Comment: KRR, this helped solve problems on several levels. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on KRR answer. Even though the chart might be working in Google spreadsheet it appears that the getBlob of the chart rechecks the source values of the chart. You need to make sure that the source values (in my case above from a spreadsheet) all have the same data type.