# Google Charts - Google Visualization arraytoDataTable not recognizing a numeric value unless "treated"

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization, google-visualization

have a look at [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/rtfwjma2/4/).

I am trying to import a value from a form field, assign it to a variable and then pass it to ***google.visualization.arrayToDataTable***.

But in both cases, even forcing the ***type: 'number'*** assignment as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722007/6589922) I always get some kind of error:

**Case 1**:

```html
<form name="myForm">
<input type="number" name="tot_btc" id="tot_btc" value="250">
```

```js
var points  = document.forms.myForm.tot_btc.value;

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', {label: 'Donuts eaten', type: 'number'}],
        //['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , points],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);
```

I get this kind of error:

[image]

as you can see **the value is acknowledged** but the chart is not drawn: it's blank.

---

**Case 2**:

```html
<form name="myForm">
<input type="number" name="tot_btc" id="tot_btc" value="250">
```

```js
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        //['Name', {label: 'Donuts eaten', type: 'number'}],
          ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , points],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);
```

I remove the ***type: 'number'*** assignment and the number is not even recognised as such.

[image]

---

**Case 3**:

Now, have a look at this:

**BUT** if I take the number from the variable and perform any simple math operation, voila! The number is recognized AND the chart is drawn .. even without forcing the *type: 'number'* recognition:

[image]

Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although you have set the `<input>` as type number,
the `value` property will always return a string, here...

```
    var points  = document.forms.myForm.tot_btc.value;
```

from [MDN - HTMLInputElement - Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), you can see the property type = string...

> `value`   `string`: Returns / Sets the current value of the control.

---

it must be converted to an actual number,
before providing the value to `arrayToDataTable`

which is why performing math on the variable causes it to work.

to correct, parse the value to a number,
using either `parseInt` or `parseFloat`...

```
    var points  = parseFloat(document.forms.myForm.tot_btc.value);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      function drawStuff() {

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
          document.getElementById('programmatic_dashboard_div'));

        // We omit "var" so that programmaticSlider is visible to changeRange.
        var programmaticSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'programmatic_control_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten',
            'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
          }
        });
//        var points  = document.forms["myForm"]["points"].value;
        var points  = parseFloat(document.forms.myForm.tot_btc.value);
        var cazzo = 81;

        var programmaticChart  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'programmatic_chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'legend': 'none',
            'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
            'pieSliceText': 'value'
          }
        });

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       // ['Name', {label: 'Donuts eaten', type: 'number'}],
          ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , points],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);

        dashboard.bind(programmaticSlider, programmaticChart);
        dashboard.draw(data);

        changeRange = function() {
          programmaticSlider.setState({'lowValue': 2, 'highValue': 5});
          programmaticSlider.draw();
        };

        changeOptions = function() {
          programmaticChart.setOption('is3D', true);
          programmaticChart.draw();
        };
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="programmatic_dashboard_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
  <table class="columns">
    <tr>
      <td>
       <div id="programmatic_control_div" style="padding-left: 2em; min-width: 250px"></div>
       <form name="myForm">
       <input type="number" name="tot_btc" id="tot_btc" value="2">
       <input type="range" onmousedown="return showInput()" onmouseup="return showInput()" name="points" min="0" max="10">
       </form>
        <div>
          <button style="margin: 1em 1em 1em 2em" onclick="changeRange();">
            Select range [2, 5]
          </button><br />
          <button style="margin: 1em 1em 1em 2em" onclick="changeOptions();">
            Make the pie chart 3D
          </button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function changeRange() {
            programmaticSlider.setState({'lowValue': 2, 'highValue': 5});
            programmaticSlider.draw();
          }

          function changeOptions() {
            programmaticChart.setOption('is3D', true);
            programmaticChart.draw();
          }
        </script>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="programmatic_chart_div"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```